# Downloads folder restores automatically

Tags: 12.04, downloads

over the last couple of days  i've noticed that each time the downloads folder is modified, ie, any new file is downloaded, previously deleted folders are restored. And the restored folders are empty, as in, they don't contain any data whatsoever.

My major issue with this is that each time this happens, i need to re-organize the entire downloads folder again and continuously remove the empty folders.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it happening with some specific download manager?

Comment: All the files that are restored are those that i've downloaded via torrents. The client i use for torrent downloads is Deluge.

Comment: Have you deleted the torrents from Deluge's download list? If you only remove the files manually, Deluge will try to start download from the begging.

Comment: I'll try that out and post as soon as a i get a result. thanks.

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot! can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was provided by Joao Andre. Basically, whenever i would clear stuff out from my Downloads folder, the same would not be done from Deluge, ie, the torrents and the associated files were removed from the folder itself, but since it still remained in Deluge's list, it'd try to download them again, resulting in a number of empty, 'ghost' folders.